# New Relic PHP application monitoring, per-application permissions

Tags: newrelic

I have a PHP/Apache stack which runs multiple sites/applications which I want to monitor with New Relic. Different development teams are handling different applications and therefore I want to be able to split them into different accounts. Each team should only have access to their application.

Is this possible with New Relic?

Another (better?) option would be to have application level user rights but that does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

I work for New Relic and Indeed you can have each New Relic monitored application report to separate accounts. Users within each account would only have visibility into the application associated with the account while a 'master' user could be configuread accross all accounts. Other organizational possibilities as well as account configurations may also be available depending upon your subscription level.

For additional insight into these options we recomend contacting your account administrator when you create your account.